# Azure Sdk for vs2013.4 does not work

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sdk-.net

It all started a few days ago when I began getting this error when starting vs2013:

[image]

That was for no apparent reason, I installed no new extensions nor update any of the existing. Didn't change any setting either.

The ActivityLog.xml shows the following:

```
<entry>
    <record>37</record>
    <time>2015/05/20 08:45:55.977</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [ResourceManagerPackage]</description>
    <guid>{7C6A3AE5-F469-4D51-B52D-50393DEC9432}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.ResourceManager.Contracts.1.0, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>38</record>
    <time>2015/05/20 08:45:55.977</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [ResourceManagerPackage]</description>
    <guid>{7C6A3AE5-F469-4D51-B52D-50393DEC9432}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.ResourceManager.Contracts.1.0, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

So far I have tried:

- devenv /safemode -> /resetskippkgs -> /installvstemplates -> /resetsettings -> /resetuserdata
- devenv /setup
- Repairing Azure SDK installation (version 2.6)
- Completely uninstalling and resintalling Azure SDK (version 2.6)

None of this worked and I can't find anything else on the web to try. Completely stumped.

Is there anything else I can try?

Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here, did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Only a complete uninstall and reinstall of vs worked

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. Did you manage to get Azure SDK 2.6 working? (my problems started after updating to Azure SDK 2.6)

Comment: After reinstalling everything worked fine

Comment: Still not working, I submitted a bug at MS...

Answer (score 1):

From the responsible team at MSFT: We haven’t identified the root cause of this issue yet, but this solution usually works in the interim.

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Find and Uninstall the Azure Resource Manager Tools (VS XX) - vX.X
   gwmi win32_product | ? {$*.Name -Like "Azure Resource Manager Tools*"} | % {msiexec /x $*.IdentifyingNumber /qb}
3. Repair the matching Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 20XX - vX.X"  (You can also do this from ARP)
   gci "$env:ProgramData\Package Cache\MicrosoftAzureTools.*.exe" -Recurse | % {. $_.FullName /modify}